# setIsLoggedin not triggering to true

Tags: reactjs

```
    const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false); 
    const handleLogin = async (email, password) => {
     try {
       const { access_token } = await login(email, password);
       const userDetails = await getUser(access_token);
       // console.log(userDetails.name);
       setUser(userDetails);
       setError(null);
       localStorage.setItem('accessToken', access_token);
       setIsLogged(true);  // -------------> not triggering 
       // console.log(isLogged);
      
       navigate('/dashboard-react');
      // console.log(localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));

      } catch (error) {
       setError(error.response.data.error);
     }
   };
```

I want the `setIsLoggedIn(true)` when the handle login function triggers but it awalys showing false

Comment: Can you post the code where you call `handleLogin` and use `isLogged`?

Comment: @Ipizzinidev
handle login
```
import { useState } from "react";
import useAuth from "./Auth";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const { handleLogin, error, isLogged } = useAuth();

    if (isLogged == true) {
        return <Navigate to="/dashboard-react" />;
    }
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        handleLogin(email, password);
    };

    return (
     
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: @@Ipizzinidev  isLogged 
const App = () => {
    const { isLogged } = useAuth();

    return (
        <>
            {/* <Router> */}
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                {isLogged === false ? (
                    <div className="container">
                        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
                            TMS
                        </Link>
                            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div

Answer (score 0):

In React, the useState hook does not set the new value synchronously, which means that the new value is not available immediately after setting it with the setState function. Rather, React schedules a state update and executes the state change asynchronously if needed.

So in your Console.log the new state is not available yet, but only in the next render cycle.

If you want to check if the variable has changed after setState, you can check for its changes in the [useEffect](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';



const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('isLogged state updated:', isLogged);
}, [isLogged]);
```

The hook takes 2 parameters. The first parameter is a function which is executed under conditions.

The 2nd parameter determines the condition. More precisely, an array of values is passed here, which are checked for change. If a change is detected, the function from the first parameter is executed.

Actually exactly the case you are trying to map.

Comment: Maik Thiele console.log('isLogged state updated:', isLogged);
 is not changing value

Comment: @ashutoshjak Unfortunately, your comment only describes your problem case, which you have already posed in the question. 
Does my answer not help you or where is exact the problem?